# Can Not click captcha checkbox using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I cannot seem to click the captcha checkbox using puppeteer on this site: https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/

What is causing this?

```
page.waitFor(500);

await page.waitForSelector("#recaptcha-anchor");

await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector("#recaptcha-anchor").parentElement.click();
});
```

Comment: What/where is your code ? That will never works, it's designed to prevent bots scraping. Only paid web services can solve this AFAIK (with real humans behind the hood). If you ask this question, you are far to solve this.

Comment: I edited it into the main post

Answer (score 1):

if you're still trying to do this, just use `document.querySelector("iframe")` or anything like that, this will probably help you because the first iframe in the page is the iframe containing the checkbox.

And you can click it!